# How can I move sink supply lines from the floor to the wall?

Tags: bathroom, water, drain, pipe

So before I make any cuts into my subfloor and wall I wanted to ask anyone with experience in this area on what my best course of action would be.

Basically, I would like to have the pipes you see coming out of the floor actually come out if the wall so when I get my new vanity I won't have to deal with hiding them/ having the vanity moved out about 6 inches. This is a second story bathroom so no access from below.

**Main Questions**

1. Should I cut the floor and wall to get a better idea of what is in there? or
2. Should I just contact a contractor/plumber to do this cause it's going to get to that point eventually?

Here's my setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the space below this floor the best course of action would be to re-route these water pipes so that the riser portion comes right up under the center of the thickness of the wall that you show here. Then you would just be opening the drywall here to put elbows on the pipes to bring them out of the wall.

Opening the wall first from this upper side would be a good thing anyway because it looks like replacement of the wall board that was behing the old cabinet could be a good thing depending what it is that is causing the dark brown and black spots.

Comment: My guess is those dark brown / black spots are where someone got wild with a torch when sweating those joints.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a second floor bathroom, so I can't access from underneath. Would that mean drilling a hole into the subfloor and jigsawing out the small portion where the pipes are?

Comment: Is the first floor part of your property? If so then you do too have access. Do the pipes come down right through the lower level ceiling? In any case access may very well mean opening up the floor from above or the ceiling from below.

Comment: @MichaelKaras It was more of a "I'd rather not tear up my ceiling downstairs to access these pipes." I guess I should mention this is my house.

Comment: Well then you'll just have to take up the floor in the space that you are remodeling. There will just be no other way to re-route the pipes. You'll have the width of the floor joists to work within to over under the lower plate of the wall. Part of the problem may be that the original routing of the drain line may be in the way.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Last comment I promise. If the black drain seen in the pic is in the walls, I shouldn't have any problem with moving the pipes in there as well (assuming there's space). Someone mentioned to me that the may be outside the wall for freezing purposes.

Comment: No problem with additional comments. Progress gets made through communications. Can you specify if the wall is indeed an outside wall? If so what type of climate region is this building located in?

Comment: @MichaelKaras It is an exterior wall, I live in the midwest, so both hot and cold seasons. I think I may be able to leave them where they are by cutting them off lower than they are and then put the vanity on top and worry about routing them up afterwards. Thoughts?

Comment: Whether you are doing the plumbing yourself, or hiring someone else, it is likely easiest to just leave them where they are, and drop the new cabinet on there. You'll have to cap them to make it easier to put the cabinet over them, but it is less work than rerouting them. What is your rational to move them - more cabinet space?

Comment: @Steven - I think the rational may have been one of two things. Some replacement vanity units are easier to install by just pushing them into place as opposed to drilling holes for pipes coming up from the floor. Of course one option with some vanity units is to notch the cabinet floor from the rear. Another reason may be due to wanting to install an open bottom pedestal type sink. These often have a stand that can somewhat hide fixture piping that comes out of the wall.